# How to extract Article URLs from a external website and store them in a list / array?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Web Development and I have a little side project which I want to build.

It's a very simple website that should list all of the articles of a particular category on my blog, for example, https://www.ceos3c.com/category/hacking/

So I would like to extract all links to actual blog posts from a category and store them in an array or something for further processing / displaying them on the links list.

I already searched a bit but most solutions were directed towards the same website. So using var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); for example. I found this code that kind of does what I want, but I somehow need to access the external URL of my blog instead of the DOM.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var thisHref = window.location.href;
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    templink = links[i].href;
    if (templink != thisHref){// if the link is not same with current page URL
        alert(links[i].href);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get Cross-Site Scripting errors most likely. Instead you will probably have to scrape with your server with something like Beautiful Soup/Python.

Comment: or use puppeteer with node.js.

Answer (score 0):

From a Javascript console, you'll only be able to **scrape** information from the current page.

You could execute an XMLHttpRequest and try to parse the result but it would be a pain in the arse ( cross site scripting, mixed active content error, Content Security Policy from your browser ...)

Below is a simple example (will only work if you are on the same website: eg https://developer.mozilla.org/fr):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/S%C3%A9curit%C3%A9/MixedContent"
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", parseResponse, false);
function parseResponse(event) {
 if(this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
 {
   if(this.status === 200)
   {
      console.log(this.responseText);
   } else {
      console.warn(this.statusText);
   }
 }
}
```

If you really want to **scrape** data from other website/pages, a better option is to develop/use a webcrawler.

A basic webcrawler will:

- Index the content of a page
- Extract raw information
- Export the data into a structured format

You should have a look on Github
https://github.com/search?q=crawler

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the answer! I am familiar with crawlers, but how would I implement one with Javascript, or whatever, to work with what I want to achieve?

Comment: If you want a JS like syntax, you should try to use/develop a webcrawler written in JS -> NodeJS App
You cant have a look at this article: 
http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-javascript-and-node-js/
If it answers your question feel free to mark it as resolved.